# Selecting specific field(child field?) from firebase in react Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

Here is my firebase:

```
"Locations" : {
   "location01" : {
     "image" : 
     "https://www.senecacollege.ca/content/dam/projects/seneca/homepage-assets/homepage_intl.jpg",
     "instructorName" : " OSMAN H.",
     "place" : "Seneca, Scarborough",
     "timing" : "TBA"
  },
  "location02" : {
     "image" : "https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C561BAQHrVTRjljcYnw/company-background_10000/0?e=2159024400&v=beta&t=fp0LWqyEnnXvxjzzdfuCHhX2jflJyhAkS0lMLXsPFw0",
     "instructorName" : "AIYAZ NOOR",
     "place" : "UTSC, Scarborough",
     "timing" : "4 PM - 6 PM"
  }
},
```

I know that if I get the data like this, then I can select/filter the specific field I want.

```
let locationsRef = db.ref('/Locations');

  locationsRef.once('value', snapshot => {
      let data = snapshot.val()
      let locationsList = Object.values(data)
      console.log(locationsList);
  })
```

This unfortunately will give all the data as an array and displays each object. If the /locations branch had many records, it would take up space and in my opinion not best practice. Is there any way to select the 'place' field ONLY. The keys 'location01' and 'location02' can be anything. So I can't do something like (location/location01), this would take me into specific branch then. I want to get the 'place' field from all the branches.

I researched alot and had no luck. Any ideas/help are much appreciated!
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the `.map` function in JavaScript.

You can map over your locations object like this:

```
const locationsRef = db.ref('/Locations');

locationsRef.once('value', snapshot => {
  let data = snapshot.val()
  let locationsList = Object.values(data)
  locationsList.map((location, index) => {
    console.log(location.place);
    // here you can do whatever you want with every single location object
    // for example return a View that displays only the place
    return <View><Text>{location.place}</Text></View>
  });
});
```

You can read more about the `.map` function in the MDN docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

P.S.
I changed your use of `let` to `const` in case your DB data is a constant that you are not changing in this particular View.

Comment: Is this the only way possible. I mean the locationsList would still have data in it if lets suppose there are 1000 objects/records in firebase. Maybe there's a much more efficient way? Or is this the only one? I've worked with oracle DB and its easy to retrieve a single field there but its first time with firebase, so just curious if theres a much more efficient way. Thank you for your response tho :)